# How to pass multiple checkbox parameters from foreach

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a form in my View with a table and on each cell i have a checkbox. I already have individual Ids for every single checkbox but I dont know how to pass them individually to controller action. I know how to pass single parameters over the "name" attribute but Im not sure on how to handle it with so many diffrent checkboxes.

View

```
@{
     bool IsOwnRegistration = false;
     foreach (var item in Model.Events.Where(i => i.UserId == Model.UserID && Convert.ToDateTime(i.Date) > dateTime))
     {
       if (item.HasCreatedOtherUsers == null)
       {
         IsOwnRegistration = true;
       }
       string Surname = "";
       string Lastname = "";
       <tr>
           @{
             foreach (var Useritem in Model.Users.Where(i => i.UserId == item.HasCreatedOtherUsers))
             {
               Surname = Useritem.Vorname;
               Lastname = Useritem.Nachname;
             }
             if (IsOwnRegistration == true)
             {
               <th style="background-color:grey; width:33%;">
                 Meine Reservation
               </th>
               <th style="width:33%;">@item.Date</th>
               <th style="width:33%;">
                 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="@item.EventId" id="@item.Date@item.EventId">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="@item.Date@item.EventId"><i style="color:red;" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                   </label>
                 </div>
               </th>
             }
             else
             {
               <th style="width:33%;">@Surname @Lastname</th>
               <th style="width:33%;">@item.Date</th>
               <th style="width:33%;">
                 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="@item.EventId" id="@item.Date@item.EventId">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="@item.Date@item.EventId"><i style="color:red;" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                   </label>
                 </div>
               </th>
             }
           }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteRegistrations(Need to get values of all checkboxes) 
{
  return RedirectToAction("HomePage");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to transmit the selected checkboxes to the action method, the checkboxes should share a common name that matches the parameter name of the action method. The following sample shows a Razor view that lists some strings in a table, creating a checkbox for each string:

```
@model  IEnumerable<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                @foreach (var s in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedValues" value="@s" id="@s" />
                            <label for="@s">@s</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the `name` attribute of the checkboxes is set to "selectedValues", the `value` attribute is set to the original string (or an id in a more complex scenario).

The form is submitted by a POST request to the following action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<string> selectedValues)
{
    return View(selectedValues);
}
```

In the POST request, all the values of all checked checkboxes are transmitted as key value pairs in the form "name=value". As all of the checkboxes share the same name, ASP.NET MVC can deserialize this into an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Can now access each value by looping through selectedvalues. Perfect, thanks:)